# Jetpack Compose TopBar and BottomBar Default Elevation content doesn't fill its container

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold, android-compose-appbar

How do I fix the topbar and bottombar doesn't fill up its container.
The topbar and bottombar uses the default Elevation respectively

You can see the Top bar doesn't fill max width and it got shadows, while the bottom bar have the text its own compose

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text( text = "TEST" ) },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = { },
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountCircle,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                },
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
           BottomNavigation
            {
                val navBackStackEntry by bottomAppBarNavController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

                bottomBarItems.forEach { mainRoute ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == mainRoute.route } == true,
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = mainRoute.icon,
                                contentDescription = stringResource(id = mainRoute.resourceId),
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text( text = stringResource(id = mainRoute.resourceId), ) },
                        onClick = { },
                        alwaysShowLabel = false // This hides the title for the unselected items
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    ){

    }
```

[image: Jetpack Compose Topbar and Bottombar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of the elevation that `TopAppBar` and `BottomNavigation` have by default and because you are using a **semitransparent color** as **`primary`** color in your theme.

You can:

- remove the elevation: `TopAppBar(elevation = 0.dp)`
- use a solid background color
- try to convert the semitransparent color to the non transparent one with something like:
  `TopAppBar(backgroundColor = Color(0xD9FFFFFF).compositeOver(Color.White))`

Comment: I would like to add that there are edges of bar this is because of content padding and if  inner boxes are required with different backgrounds contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp) is required